# SQL Server 2012 "Application cannot start" after installing Visual Studio 2008

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2008

Microsoft SQL Server 2012 is installed and was working fine until I installed Visual Studio 2008. When installing VS2008 completed VS2008 would not start, I checked to see if SQL Server 2012 would start and it would NOT.

I found out the VS2008 Needed the dte80.olb in a different directory, once I copied the dte80.olb to the proper directory VS2008 runs perfectly, However Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Still will not start. "application cannot start" Message Box

There are NO Event log errors in event viewer.

I have tried deleting the Registry Config folder, still no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this problem!! Using Microsoft Process Monitor I was able to see that some path information was not found!

You need to copy **dte80a.olb**

**From** C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSEn

**TO** C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\

I hope this will fix all of your issues like it did for me!